# why clone not working?

Tags: java, oop

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code unreported exception java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
at Test.main(Test.java:13)
Java Result: 1

```
 public class  Color
 {
     public String ColorName()
     {
         return "Red";
     }
 }
 public class Test extends Color
 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Color MyShirt = new Color();
       Color MyBag = (Color) MyShirt.clone();

       System.out.println(MyShirt.ColorName());
       System.out.println(MyBag.ColorName());
    }
 }
```

Comment: How do you think `clone()` works and why?

Comment: i expect output
Red
Red

Comment: See this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't implement `Cloneable`, and `Object` has a default implementation of `clone()` that only throws `CloneNotSupportedException`; I think you wanted something like this

```
public class Color implements Cloneable {
  protected String name = "Red";

  public String ColorName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public Object clone() {
    Color c = new Color();
    c.name = this.name;
    return c;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't true: "Object has a default implementation of clone() that _only_ throws CloneNotSupportedException". Read the API, implementing Cloneable will cause Object's clone() to return a shallow copy, and so by convention should call super.clone() when overriding. Override to grant public and to clone mutable structures etc. Subclasses of Object are permitted still to throw CloneNotSupportedException if they want. Bartek has a good latter half of answer, however constructors aren't always available for situations of polymorphism and generics. Mentioned "Effective Java" does have more detail

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct in pointing out that your class needs to implement `Clonable` and override the `clone()` method in order to work as expected:

```
class Color implements Cloneable{
    @Override 
    public Color clone(){
        Color c = new Color();
        c.name = this.name;
        return c;
    }
    // other methods
}
```

However, the most important thing about `clone()` is that you should always avoid using it.

[Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) explains in his book ["Effective Java"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), that `clone()` is deeply broken and rightly recommends using a copy constructor instead. You can read more about it [here](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Instead of using `clone()`, you should declare a copy constructor like this:

```
class Color{
    public Color(){ /* ... */ } // default constructor
    public Color(Color c){
        this.name = c.name; // copy all attributes
    }
    // other methods
}
```

and then use it to copy the object:

```
Color c = new Color();
Color other = new Color(c); // returns a copy of c
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class must implement java.lang.Cloneable interface.

```
public class  Color implements Cloneable
{
    public String ColorName()
    {
        return "Red";
    }

    @Override
    public Color clone() {
        //return your cloned Color instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class does not implement the Cloneable interface, hence is why this exception was thrown.  This can be found right in Java API.